# How to create multiple roles through discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make my discord bot create multiple roles through a command. But it simply doesn't work. Here is what I have done so far:

```
@commands.command()
    async def create_roles(self, ctx):
        guild = self.client.get_guild(783547639944839178)
        channel = self.client.get_channel(809683610058752010)
        await guild.create_role(name="red", color=discord.Color.value('F51720'))
        await guild.create_role(name="skyblue", color=discord.Colour.value('11A7BB'))
        await guild.create_role(name="yellow", color=discord.Colour.value('F8D210'))
        await channel.send("Done.")
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command create_roles:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\cogs\roles.py", line 14, in create_roles
    await guild.create_role(name="red", colour=discord.Colour.value('F51720'))
TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wave computer\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share with us the error/errors that you are getting? Or at least the output from using that command.

Comment: oh thank you for the reminder, i just did that.

Comment: Your command is not working because you have a typo. The paramater name for `guild.create_role` shall be `colour`, not `color`.

Comment: even after changing it to ```colour```, it didn't work. help?

Comment: And you still get the same error?

Comment: yes, i'm getting the same error

Comment: Can you edit your code with the whole traceback?

Comment: i just did, please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit late, but here is the solution.
You used `discord.Color.value` a bit wrong. For the colors you can use either a `HEX` or `RGB` code.
For a RGB code Discord has this function: `discord.Color.from_rgb()` and for a hex code you can simply define the color, for example:
`customred = FF0000`.
For your code I took once the RGB variant:

```py
@commands.command()
async def create_roles(self, ctx):
    guild = self.client.get_guild(GuildID)
    channel = self.client.get_channel(ChannelID)
    await guild.create_role(name="red", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(245, 23, 32))
    await guild.create_role(name="skyblue", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(17, 167, 187))
    await guild.create_role(name="yellow", color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(248, 210, 16))
    await ctx.send("Done.")
```

You can of course define the color beforehand - `cred = discord.Colour.from_rgb(248, 210, 16))` - and then use only `cred` as color:

```py
await guild.create_role(name="red", color=cred)
```