# How do I change a role color using a hex color code argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to change the color of role using a command with a hex color code argument (the name of role is the name of the user). I tried the following code but the bot does nothing. It has admin permissions and discord.Intents.all()

```py
@client.command(name="color")
async def role_color(ctx, arg):
    name = ctx.author.name
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=name)
    await role.edit(color=f"0x{arg}")
```

Comment: I made an answer to a similar question a while ago. Is the following answer helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167818/how-to-create-multiple-roles-through-discord-py-bot/66404603#66404603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Role.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.edit), you have to pass in an instance of [discord.Colour](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Colour) or an int value. This means you have to convert `arg`. Thankfully, you are expecting `arg` to be hexcode so we can just convert it to int right away (no need to add "0x").

```py
await role.edit(color=int(arg, 16))
```